# What Defines a Utah Accent?

Tags: word-usage, dialects, accent

I have heard a number of people refer to the "Utah accent."  What is it that distinguishes a Utah accent from others?

I have noticed that, in some cases, people from Utah omit the 't' from words such as 'Layton' and 'mountain.'  In other cases, it seems like they pronounce 'milk' with an 'e' instead of an 'i.'  'Creek' sounds like 'crick.' 'Mormon' like 'Marmon.' I am not sure if any of these are specific to Utah.

Finally, what about differences between regions, for example, what is a Cache Valley accent?

Comment: I got a bunch of hits on this query on Google: *"what is a utah accent"*.

Comment: Not sure who close-voted this, but if the reason behind the close-vote is what Kristina describes, let's not forget that Googling does not constitute General Reference. This is not a question that is easily answered in an authoritative manner by any commonly available reference work that I know of (except perhaps Wikipedia).

Comment: I can't define a Utah accent, but I can confirm that the pronunciation of "creek" as "crick" happens in several areas. Specifically, it shows up in several varieties of Appalachian accents (my grandmother is from PA, and she says it that way).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, it's not apparent if OP did any research on his own before posting the questions.  Based on the information I gleaned from the results of my single query, it does seem that there is plenty of general reference information available.

Comment: @Kristina I'll grant you the lack of research. But when I Google, I get only a slew of blog posts, forum threads, YouTube videos, and e-zine articles. Nothing I would call General References in the sense of the term employed on ELU.

Comment: The only specifically Utah accent features that I know of is the /or/ ~ /ar/ alpha switch, which shows up in place names like _American Fork_, where _fork_ is pronounced /fark/. Similarly, _car_ is pronounced /kor/, while _core_ is pronounced /kar/. It's not a common kind of change, and it may be diminished in extent since I lived in Utah in the 1960s. See the charming essay by Wayne Booth on "Farkism and Hyperyorkism".

Comment: i lived in utah for some time!  greatest snow on earth.  purely fwiw, i for one didn't notice any accent.  (it seems fairly unbelievable there could be a cache valley or park city accent.)  John, I really didn't/don't notice the vowel switch you explain, fwiw.

Comment: **ANYTHING CAN BE GOOGLED!!!!!!!!!!** That doesn't make the results authoritative, reliable, or correct. This is not a general reference question, and anyone who voted to close it as such needs to have their close-voting privileges revoked. Enough already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This podcast sheds light on the issue: http://radiowest.kuer.org/post/speaking-american-speaking-utahn It is an interview with two language experts. They talk about regional accents in general, but focus on Utah specifically. Interestingly enough, according to the folks in this episode, most of the things that people identify with being unique to Utah are actually not unique to Utah.

Answer (score 4):

A few examples of things I've noticed (especially in Cache Valley) are:

- pronouncing the word "deal" and "real", "peel", etc. as "dill",
  "rill", "pill" etc. ....similar for the words "really" ("rilly") and
  "dealer" ("diller")
- pronouncing the word "our" the same way most
  pronounce "are"
- pronouncing words like "light", "right", "bright",
  etc. as "loyt" and "royt", "broyt"
- Pronouncing "luggage", "garbage"    and "baggage" as "lugg-eege",
  "garb-eege" and "bagg-eege".
- pronouncing the word "it" as "uht" as in "Where is uht?" and "Give
  uht to me!"
- pronouncing the word "different" as "diff-ernt"
- pronouncing "Monday", "Tuesday", etc. as "Mon-dee", "Tues-dee", etc.
- pronouncing "You're" as "yerr"
- Also, the letter "r" is pronounced    slightly differently than
  anywhere else I've noticed, although I    can't quite describe it.

Rod Tueller who sometimes helps broadcast Utah State Unviersity Basketball games on KVNU has a classic Cache Valley accent.

Comment: "or"/"ar" conflation and "it" -> "uht" are similar to St. Louis accents

Answer (score 2):

Currently a Utah resident and have been for 25 years. (don't judge me :-P)

But I can confirm that I catch myself frequently stating "mountain" as "moun'ain", Layton as "lay'on".

However, I have never vocalized "creek" as "crick" (though it seems to be about 50% of those I've come across) or "Mormon" as "Marmon".

I personally would say that the Utah accent is distinct because it's similar but not completely 'country' mixed with an almost southern twist.

As far as different areas of Utah having their own play on the accent goes: yes, in Provo I've noticed a fair amount of 'better' annunciation of words like mountain where the 't' is actually heard (though still faint and abrupt) along with habits of emphasizing words in the sentence, as a whole, differently then what I would expect to hear.

Example- in Provo (generalized and subjective) any sentence that begins with "I" where the actual emphasis is placed on a verb, "I like *runnin'*!", tends to be pronounced with a double emphasis, "*I* like *runnin'*!", and to me sounds terrible. 
In opposition, hearing this same sentence in West Valley sounds more appropriate as there doesn't seem to be the initial emphasis on the beginning "I".

As a side note, a very prominent part of the Utah speech pattern is the use of spin-off phrases. "I'm *hella* excited!" turns into "I'm *hecka* excited!" and not just for the obvious reasons. I've found that most people I've come across who have different religious beliefs than the majority of the state, still have adopted 'hecka' as a preference to 'hella', though the same person will have no inhibitions to dropping 'f' bombs.

Then there's the 'uh' sound in most words. You don't here, "*You* all take care now!", or "*Ya'll* take care now!", but instead, "*Y'uh* all take care now!".

And finally the other speech pattern that I've noticed to be very common here is the contractile contraction. "It's all fun and games until someone gets hurt." turns into " 'S'all fun'n games s'til' someone gets'hurt."

Answer (score 1):

The [Dictionary of American Regional English](http://www.daredictionary.com) uses a region called "Utah".  You can investigate the features of that region on that web site.  (Subscription required.  Perhaps you library has one.)